# Pass multiple variables via URL and reading all of them on next page

Tags: php, url, parameters, get

I have a link that points to a webpage e.g. "land.php".
The link looks like this:

```
<a href="land.php?id=1&cd=a">link</a>
```

this takes me to the page land.php where I can read the first parametere with `$id` (and it is equal to 1, correctly), but I cannot read the second one. I either tried with `$cd` or `$_GET['cd']`. None of them works.

if I tried `isset($cd)` it says `false`. Same thing for `isset($_GET['cd'])`.

How can I pass the second parameter too (and read it!)?

EDIT:

some code (so people are happy. I think it's pointless in this case..).

land.php

```
<?php
if($_GET['cd']==a)
    echo "<h2>HI</h2>";
else
    echo "<h2>BY</h2>";
?>
```

if I use `$cd` instead of `$_GET['cd']` it doesn't work anyway..

EDIT2 I don't get any syntax error, it just doesn't behave how expected.

Comment: What output does `var_dump($_GET);` give you? Also, check if the parameters are still on the URL when you arrive at `land.php`, there might be something else in your code messing that up.

Comment: nothing. it prints an empty string. what do you mean if they are still there? when I mouse over the link my browser shows me all parameters so they are there.

Comment: I meant when you arrive at the `land.php` page. Be sure to run the `var_dump()` function on the `land.php` file (after clicking the link).

Comment: Can you show more code from `land.php` (please copy and paste)? I have a feeling the problem lies there

Comment: land.php is a simple if else which is supposed to print a string if the parameter cd is a, or another string otherwise. the point is 'cd' is always not set.

Comment: @Danny Is it really so hard to post some code? Please read http://sscce.org/ for hints on asking technical questions

Comment: Of course $_GET will be empty unless you arrive at the page from a form with its method set to GET   See  http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp

Comment: @Mawg Totally incorrect. The `$_GET` super global is populated with the parameters from the URL query string. You do not need to arrive via a form

Comment: @Danny Your code *contained* syntax errors (extra closing parenthesis). I assume from your edit that you didn't actually copy and paste **real code**

Comment: I am try to do that simple page and it doesn't work. that is why I am asking for help, and that is why I didn't want to post any code. should I post every possible try I make? Anyway that code doesn't work as stated in OP.

Answer (score 1):

The value is stored in `$_GET['cd']`.

Try printing out the `$_GET` array, with `print_r($_GET);`

[print_r($_GET)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) should output

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [cd] => a
)
```

This should ofcourse be in the `land.php` page, as the get variables are only available in the requested page.

Comment: @Danny `print_r($_GET)` should never display `1`. At the least it should be `Array()`

Comment: Use `print_r($_GET, true)` if used in echo statement. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php for usage.

Comment: if I don't use it in echo it prints nothing.

Comment: as I said print_r($_GET) doesn't print anything

Comment: Try to place this at the very beginning at the file:
`<?php die("<pre>".print_r($_GET, true)."</pre>"); ?>`. It **will** print out the entire `$_GET` array. Moving it down, line by line, will give you an indication of what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your server might be set up to accept semicolon instead of ampersands. Try replacing & with ;

Comment: no, if i try ";" it's like I don't split the parameters at all. It all gets incorporated in the first parameter. which is a problem.

Comment: That is incorrect. $_GET should be populated with the parameters in the query string, regardless of its origin. So manually typed URLs, URLs from anchors and from-generated URLs are all valid input.

Comment: why "&" is actually used as separator but then only one parameter (the first one) is passed to the next page?

Comment: It seams like the statement i argued have been deleted. I do not know why only one parameter is passes on but i suspect its either some bad config or you accidentally unset it somewhere. You should try to search your code for unsets or try running your script on a different server.

Answer (score 0):

`$_GET['cd']` is the correct syntax. Are you actually on the `land.php` page, ie does your browser's address bar read something like

```
example.com/land.php?id=1&cd=a
```

Also, it looks like you have `register_globals` enabled if you can read `$id`. This is a very bad idea.

---

### Update

Your code snippet contains syntax errors. I recommend the following, including enabling decent error reporting for development

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

if(isset($_GET['cd']) && $_GET['cd'] == 'a') {
    echo "<h2>HI</h2>";
} else {
    echo "<h2>BY</h2>";
}
```

Comment: so what I should use? $cd? It doesn't work anyway. That's why I didn't want to post code because I tried a lot of different things.

Comment: no, my browser ends up in example.com/land.html. there is a redirecting apparently, but this doesn't prevernt "id" to be passed. why the same doesn't happen to "cd"?